# How to give access to inactive user profile?

Tags: users

I guess the title is obvious. I have built a Drupal 7 website showing a view of the previous Users (inactive profiles).

As an admin, I can access these profiles but I need anonymous users to have that permission too (view "previous" or "old" members profiles).

Is there any module to add that kind of permission?

Thanks and sorry for my English ;)

Comment: How about `admin/people/permissions` -> User -> View user profiles -> Anonymous Users ?

Comment: I need : User -> View INACTIVE user profiles -> Anonymous Users. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I think it can be easilly done by patching Core in `/modules/user/user.module` in `user_view_access($account)`. You need to change `return (is_object($account) && $account->status);` into `return (is_object($account));`, I think

Comment: It worked perfectly. To be sure I got it, you just modified the user.module so the account access is allowed without considering the user account status (active or blocked), right? Besides, is there any module that add a line in Permissions for that kind of access? Thanks anyway.

Comment: I couldn't find any `hooks` for the job so I don't think there are any modules that would do this, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The View Profiles Permissions module will work for that purpose: https://www.drupal.org/project/view_profiles_perms.

In order for this to work, you will also need to give your blocked users a Role.

It is not the primary function of the View Profiles Permissions module, but there is more information about this specific issue here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2490934

Additionally, You can use the Rules module to automatically assign a role to users when they become blocked.

Steps:

1. Install and Enable the View Profiles Permissions module
2. Create a role called "Blocked"
3. Give permissions to anonymous users to "Access to *Blocked* profiles"
4. Assign the "Blocked" role to all users who are blocked (aka Inactive, Old, Disabled)
5. Extra Credit: Install/Enable the Rules module and a new Rule that automatically assigns the Blocked" role to users when they become blocked.

Comment: Your solution seems OK, I will try it next time I need that kind of function. I always prefer a module-based solution. Thanks for your answer.